# Why VS 2010 is best IDE for SP 2010

Tags: 2010, visual-studio

I need to find the links where Microsoft says VS 2010 Pro/Ultimate edition is  the best IDE for developing solutions for SharePoint 2010.

I know this question is an old question, compared to the software products I have mentioned .But I need to tell the customer because of this and this reasons we can not develop portal applications using VS 2008 for SP 2010.

Any links, sources, any MS articles are highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following details requirements for developing SharePoint solutions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231582.aspx

Update:
The following MSDN article also provides more specific details about VS version:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539321(v=office.14).aspx

The quote from the above article clearly articulates VS2010 is required: "We recommend that you not use earlier versions of Visual Studio for SharePoint Foundation development, because Visual Studio 2010 includes tools to systematize and partially automate many important parts of the development process, especially the packaging of your SharePoint projects into Features and Solutions."

Comment: I don't think that there is any advice described whick VS version has to be used

Comment: The following MSDN article provides guidance on VS versions for sharepoint: "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539321(v=office.14).aspx"

Comment: I believe this is quite clear: "We recommend that you not use earlier versions of Visual Studio for SharePoint Foundation development, because Visual Studio 2010 includes tools to systematize and partially automate many important parts of the development process, especially the packaging of your SharePoint projects into Features and Solutions."

Comment: Russell, am getting the error message ,.Can you pls provide the correct URL.  The error message  is "We're sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."

Comment: Try the link in the answer

Comment: yes, Russell, with the valid link I agree ;-)